# Is it possible to undo an accidental "hg unshelve"?

Tags: mercurial

Now my there's an extra few hundred lines of code in my project, scattered over half a dozen classes, and I'm not looking forward to tracking them down one by one.

Comment: Do you mean you did an `unshelve` into a dirty work-tree, making it dirtier?  (Presumably if not you can simply re-`shelve`.)

Comment: @torek Yes, that's what I did. I sorted it out in the meantime - took me a few hours - but I'd still like to know if it's solvable in an easier way.

Comment: Not as far as I know, no.

Comment: See also [Is there a way to get a mercurial shelf back after a merge mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49457264/411282).  My question is more about getting the content of the original shelf patch back, where this post is more about undoing changes that got accidentally mixed in with working directory differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, but this is an avoidable problem**

Instead of doing `hg shelve`, do `hg commit --secret`.  This will create a "real" commit in the repository, which can be rebased or stripped ([`hg strip`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension)) when you no longer need it.  It can also be folded into another changeset using `hg histedit` or `hg fold` (the latter requires the Evolve extension, which is experimental at the time of writing, while the former is interactive and may be hard to script).

The `--secret` flag ensures the changeset will not be accidentally pushed until you manually run `hg phase -d REV` on the changeset.

Comment: Or you can use MQ and just `qpush`/`qpop` the changes as much as needed.

Comment: MQ is almost-but-not-quite deprecated.  I wouldn't recommend it for new projects.

Comment: i didn't know. what's superseded it?

Comment: The evolve extension, when it's ready.  In the meantime, `hg histedit` is close enough.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with a few steps. The help for unshelve specifies "If a shelved change is applied successfully, the bundle that contains the shelved changes is moved to a backup location (.hg/shelve-backup)." So hg update --clean will return you to the pre-unshelve state, unless you added changes in the mean-time, in which case you need to figure out how to recover the world prior to the unwanted patches. Then you can re-apply the patches stored in the backup individually if you wish to essentially re-do the unshelve under whatever conditions you prefer. In any event, the back-up contains the data you thought was missing.