# Is there a way to get a mercurial shelf back after a merge mistake?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, unshelve

When I unshelve, it uses mercurial's merge capability, but I'm not seeing any way to get back the original shelved patch and redo  things if I've completed the merge with an error.  Aside from searching backup drives, is there any way to do that?  (either to undo the unshelve action and put the shelf back, or to see what was in the patch file)

Comment: I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284913/411282) that suggests I shouldn't have used a shelf.  I do like the way shelves keep old snippets out of the way, though.  (And I've already shelved!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it — by looking around in the `.hg` directory.  Simply find the directory `.hg/shelve-backup/`.  The original patch is written there.

I now see this is mentioned in `hg help unshelve` though I had missed it before now (and it does not say the name of the directory)

```
After a successful unshelve, the shelved changes are stored in a backup
directory. Only the N most recent backups are kept. N defaults to 10 but
can be overridden using the "shelve.maxbackups" configuration option.
```

Comment: For completion, recover using `hg import --no-commit [NAME].patch`.